# 404 detection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http-status-code-404

In my JavaScript I'm trying to redirect to third party page.  It can open a page either in a new window or inside a frame depends on a user settings.  Something like this:

```
if (newWindow)
{
   window.open(url, targer);
}
else
{
   theFrame = url;
}
```

What I want to do is to display my custom page in case a third party site is down or page is unavailable.  Basically in case of 404 error.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative idea... 
You can check target url with server side language.

For PHP: with Curl you can get http status of url.

http_code is what you are looking for curl_getinfo ( $ch [, int $opt = 0 ] )

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: +1 for workaround but I bet Vadim wants a pure javascript version.

Comment: There is no possiblty forany javascript solution. in fact if there is. it's a dangereous bug might be devastating...

Comment: with ASP.Net i think it must something like this. which is very easier.  

HttpWebRequest webrequest =
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://domain.com/urlnotfound.html");
HttpWebResponse httpresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
Response.Write(httpresponse.StatusCode);

comment box is not good to paste codes... try this url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you cannot detect anything about the content of another window or frame -- including whether it actually even loaded -- if it is on a different domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Following @risyasin advise I solved my problem on the server side using ASP.NET.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    HttpWebResponse response;
    try
    {
        var request =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.someSite.com/camdsa");
        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx?status="
+ webException.Status);
        return;
    } }
```

You can read about my solution at this [link](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/detect-when-another-site-is-unavailable-404-detection/).